# C++ while loop using bisection method. Help on break

Tags: c++, while-loop, bisection

I need some help here. Please excuse the complexity of the code. Basically, I am looking to use the bisection method to find a value "Theta" and each i increment.
I know that all the calculations work fine when I know the Theta, and I have the code run to just simply calculate all the values, but when I introduce a while loop and the bisection method to have the code approximate Theta, I can't seem to get it to run correctly. I am assuming I have my while loop set up incorrectly....

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>    // std::max

using namespace std;

double FuncM(double theta, double r, double F, double G, double Gprime, double d_t, double sig);

double FuncM(double theta, double r, double F, double G, double Gprime, double d_t, double sig)
{
    double eps = 0.0001;
    return ((log(max((r + (theta + F - 0.5 * G * Gprime ) * d_t), eps))) / sig); 
}

double FuncJSTAR(double m, double x_0, double d_x);

double FuncJSTAR(double m, double x_0, double d_x)
{
    return (int(((m - x_0) / d_x)+ 0.5));
}

double FuncCN(double m, double x_0, double j, double d_x);

double FuncCN(double m, double x_0, double j, double d_x)
{
    return (m - x_0 - j * d_x);
}

double FuncPup(double d_t, double cn, double d_x);

double FuncPup(double d_t, double cn, double d_x)
{
    return (((d_t + pow(cn, 2.0)) / (2.0 * pow(d_x, 2.0))) + (cn / (2.0 * d_x)));
}

double FuncPdn(double d_t, double cn, double d_x);

double FuncPdn(double d_t, double cn, double d_x)
{
    return (((d_t + pow(cn, 2.0)) / (2.0 * pow(d_x, 2.0))) - (cn / (2.0 * d_x)));
}

double FuncPmd(double pd, double pu);

double FuncPmd(double pd, double pu)
{
    return (1 - pu - pd);
}

int main()
{
    const int Maturities = 5;
    const double EPS = 0.00001;

    double TermStructure[Maturities][2] = {
        {0.5 , 0.05},
        {1.0 , 0.06},
        {1.5 , 0.07},
        {2.0 , 0.075},
        {3.0 , 0.085}               };

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    vector<double> Price(Maturities);

    double Initial_Price = 1.00;

    for (int i = 0; i < Maturities; i++)
        {
            Price[i] = Initial_Price * exp(-TermStructure[i][1] * TermStructure[i][0]);
        }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int j_max = 8;
    int j_range = ((j_max * 2) + 1);
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Set up vector of possible j values
    vector<int> j_value(j_range);

    for (int j = 0; j < j_range; j++)
        {
            j_value[j] = j_max - j;
        }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    double dt = 0.5;
    double dx = sqrt(3 * dt);
    double sigma = 0.15;
    double mean_reversion = 0.2; // "a" value
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    double r0 = TermStructure[0][1]; // Initialise r(0) in case no corresponding dt rate in term structure
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    double x0 = log(r0) / sigma;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    vector<double> r_j(j_range); // rate at each j
    vector<double> F_r(j_range);
    vector<double> G_r(j_range);
    vector<double> G_prime_r(j_range);

    for(int j = 0; j < j_range; j++)
        {
            if (j == j_max)
                {
                    r_j[j] = r0;
                }
            else
                {
                    r_j[j] = exp((x0 + j_value[j]*dx) * sigma);
                }

            F_r[j] = -mean_reversion * r_j[j];
            G_r[j] = sigma * r_j[j];
            G_prime_r[j] = sigma;
        }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    vector<vector<double>> m((j_range), vector<double>(Maturities));
    vector<vector<int>> j_star((j_range), vector<int>(Maturities));
    vector<vector<double>> Central_Node((j_range), vector<double>(Maturities));
    vector<double> Theta(Maturities - 1);

    vector<vector<double>> Pu((j_range), vector<double>(Maturities));
    vector<vector<double>> Pd((j_range), vector<double>(Maturities));
    vector<vector<double>> Pm((j_range), vector<double>(Maturities));

    vector<vector<double>> Q((j_range), vector<double>(Maturities));// = {}; // Arrow Debreu Price. Initialised all array values to 0
    vector<double> Q_dt_sum(Maturities);// = {}; // Sum of Arrow Debreu Price at each time step. Initialised all array values to 0

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    double Theta_A, Theta_B, Theta_C;
    int JSTART;
    int JEND;
    int TempStart;
    int TempEnd;
    int max;
    int min;
    vector<vector<int>> Up((j_range), vector<int>(Maturities));
    vector<vector<int>> Down((j_range), vector<int>(Maturities));

//  Theta[0] = 0.0498039349327417;
//  Theta[1] = 0.0538710670441647;
//  Theta[2] = 0.0181648634139392;
//  Theta[3] = 0.0381183886467521;

    for(int i = 0; i < (Maturities-1); i++)
        {
            Theta_A = 0.00;
            Theta_B = TermStructure[i][1];
            Q_dt_sum[0] = Initial_Price;
            Q_dt_sum[i+1] = 0.0;

            while (fabs(Theta_A - Theta_B) >= 0.0000001)
                {
                max = 1;
                min = 10;

                if (i == 0)
                    {
                        JSTART = j_max;
                        JEND = j_max;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        JSTART = TempStart;
                        JEND = TempEnd;
                    }   

                for(int j = JSTART; j >= JEND; j--)
                    {

                        Theta_C = (Theta_A + Theta_B) / 2.0; // If Theta C is too low, the associated Price will be higher than Price from initial term structure. (ie P(Theta C) > P(i+2) for Theta C < Theta)
                        // If P_C > P(i+2), set Theta_B = Theta_C, else if P_C < P(i+2), set Theta_A = Theta_C, Else if P_C = P(i+2), Theta_C = Theta[i]
                        //cout << Theta_A << "  " << Theta_B << "       " << Theta_C << endl;
                        m[j][i] = FuncM(Theta[i], r_j[j], F_r[j], G_r[j], G_prime_r[j], dt, sigma);
                        j_star[j][i] = FuncJSTAR(m[j][i], x0, dx);
                        Central_Node[j][i] = FuncCN(m[j][i], x0, j_star[j][i], dx);
                        Pu[j][i] = FuncPup(dt, Central_Node[j][i], dx);
                        Pd[j][i] = FuncPdn(dt, Central_Node[j][i], dx);
                        Pm[j][i] = FuncPmd(Pd[j][i], Pu[j][i]);

                        for (int p = 0; p < j_range; p++)
                            {
                                Q[p][i] = 0; // Clear Q array
                            }

                        Q[j_max][0] = Initial_Price;
                        Q[j_max -(j_star[j][i]+1)][i+1]     = Q[j_max - (j_star[j][i]+1)][i+1] + Q[j][i] * Pu[j][i] * exp(-r_j[j] * dt); 
                        Q[j_max -(j_star[j][i]  )][i+1]     = Q[j_max - (j_star[j][i]  )][i+1] + Q[j][i] * Pm[j][i] * exp(-r_j[j] * dt); 
                        Q[j_max -(j_star[j][i]-1)][i+1]     = Q[j_max - (j_star[j][i]-1)][i+1] + Q[j][i] * Pd[j][i] * exp(-r_j[j] * dt);
                    }

                    for (int j = 0; j < j_range; j++)
                        {
                            Up[j][i] = j_star[j][i] + 1;
                            Down[j][i] = j_star[j][i] - 1;

                            if (Up[j][i] > max)
                                {
                                    max = Up[j][i];
                                }

                            if ((Down[j][i] < min) && (Down[j][i] > 0))
                                {
                                    min = Down[j][i];
                                }
                        }

                        TempEnd = j_max - (max);
                        TempStart = j_max - (min);

                        for (int j = 0; j < j_range; j++)
                            {
                                Q_dt_sum[i+1] = Q_dt_sum[i+1] + Q[j][i] * exp(-r_j[j] * dt);                
                                cout << Q_dt_sum[i+1] << endl;
                            }


                        if (Q_dt_sum[i+1] == Price[i+2])
                            {
                                Theta[i] = Theta_C;
                                break;
                            }

                        if (Q_dt_sum[i+1] > Price[i+2])
                            {
                                Theta_B = Theta_C;
                            }
                        else if (Q_dt_sum[i+1] < Price[i+2])
                            {
                                Theta_A = Theta_C;
                            }

                }
        cout << Theta[i] << endl;       
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see that you are doing `float` comparisons, refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison

Comment: Ok. I understand the difficulty with floating point comparison. If I change to the following code it still does not work.

Comment: "I can't seem to get it to run correctly". Define correctly? You need to tell the inputs, the expected and the actual output for us to help further.

Comment: Ok. I understand the problem with comparing floating point, but if I add the following, it still does not work. so I can only assume it is my while loop implementation.  if (abs(Q_dt_sum[i+1] - Price[i+2]) <= 0.00000001)
 {
  Theta[i] = Theta_C;
  break;
 }
     
if (Q_dt_sum[i+1] > Price[i+2] + 0.00000001)
 {
  Theta_B = Theta_C;
 }
else if (Q_dt_sum[i+1] < Price[i+2] - 0.00000001)
 {
  Theta_A = Theta_C;
 }

Comment: when I run the code, I expect the while loop to keep recalculating Theta_c until the Q_dt_sum = P. however in keeps calculating Q_dt_sum and does not stop when it gets close to P.

Comment: I would suggest you create an MCVE (refer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and edit the question to share the relevant details. Comments are not meant for that.

Comment: expected output is.....//  Theta[0] = 0.0498039349327417;
//  Theta[1] = 0.0538710670441647;
//  Theta[2] = 0.0181648634139392;
//  Theta[3] = 0.0381183886467521;

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my bad. I had a value being called incorrectly.
All good.